# How do i disable a button in a table row that is generated with *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table that generates it's rows using an *ngFor as :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of basicTable.data; let i = index">
      
      <th class="th_class_for_id td" scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
      <td class="td">
        {{item.inventryName}}
      </td>
      <td class="td">
        <nz-button-group>
          <button nz-button nzType="primary"><i nz-icon nzType="edit" (click)="Edit(item)" nzTheme='fill'
              style="color: rgb(223, 236, 236);"> </i></button>
          <button nz-button nzType="primary"><i nz-icon nzType="delete" (click)="Delete(item)" nzTheme='fill'
              style="color: rgb(223, 236, 236);"> </i></button>
          <button nz-button nzType="primary" [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="onDisableUser(i)"><i nz-icon nzType="exclamation-circle" nzTheme='fill'
                style="color: rgb(223, 236, 236);"> </i></button>

        </nz-button-group>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

The ts file is:

```
isDisabled = false;

  onDisableUser(ind){

    console.log("button pressed @ index:" +ind);
    this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
  }
```

now here I added the `[disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="onDisableUser(i)"`  but what this is doing is that when I press the button , let's say at first row, it disables all the buttons on adjacent rows.
I don't want that, I want to disable the button I am pressing. How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need an array to hold the state of each button like below :

```
// initialize the states when data arrived
buttonStates = Array(this.basicTable.data.length).fill(false); // all enabled
```

And in your template check the state array like this:

```
 <button nz-button nzType="primary" [disabled]="buttonStates[i]" (click)="onDisableUser(i)">
   <i nz-icon nzType="exclamation-circle" nzTheme='fill'
                style="color: rgb(223, 236, 236);"></i>
 </button>
```

And your click handler will be like this :

```
onDisableUser(ind){ 
   this.buttonStates[ind]= !this.buttonStates[ind];
}
```